# Accessing static member of generic class from a decorator

Tags: typescript, generics, inheritance

I have a decorated class:

```
@Decorator
class Entity {
    public static member: string[] = [];
}
```

With a decorator:

```
function Decorator<T extends { new(...args: any[]): Entity }>(constructor: T) {
  return class extends constructor {
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...args);
      // Do some things
      constructor.prototype.member.map((v: string) => {
        // Do things with the elements of the static array.
      });
    }
  };
}
```

Although this works, by using `constructor.prototype`which is of type `any` I lose the typechecking of `member` that is already in the prototype as an array of strings.

Is there a solution without losing the typechecking?

**Edit**: I've tested also:

```
function Decorator<T extends { prototype: typeof Entity; new(...args: any[]): Entity; }>(constructor: T) {
  return class extends constructor {
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...args);
      // Do some things
      constructor.prototype.member.map((v) => {
        // Do things with the elements of the static array.
      });
    }
  };
}
```

but this gives an error in the line `@Decorator`:

> Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'Entity'.'

**Edit2**: I've tested too:

```
function Decorator<T extends typeof Entity>(constructor: T) {
  // This works and returns an Entity.
  const x = new constructor({} as any);
  // This doesn't work. Tsc says: 'Type 'T' is not a constructor function type.'
  return class extends constructor {
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...args);
      // This now works:  
      constructor.member.map((v) => {
        // ...
      });
    }
  };
}
```

but this gives an error in the line `@Decorator`:

> Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'Entity'.'

Comment: I assume you're trying to decorate *subclasses* of `Entity`, right?  If you're only decorating `Entity`, I don't understand why you're trying to jump through hoops with generics.

Comment: If you're unwilling to use type assertions, I don't think this is possible.  It seems like a bug to me; you might want to file one at [TypeScript on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues), referencing the [checkin which introduced mixins](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13743).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
(constructor.prototype as typeof Entity).member...
```

Then you'll have type safety, for example:

```
(constructor.prototype as typeof Entity).member2..
```

Will result in:

> Property 'member2' does not exist on type 'typeof Entity'.

---

#### Edit

You can't do that.
Static memebers/functions are **not** part of the prototype, to take what you wanted to do, it should look like this:

```
function Decorator<T extends { prototype: Entity; new(...args: any[]): Entity; }>(constructor: T) { ... }
```

(difference is `prototype: Entity` and not `typeof Entity`), then the error you received will go away.
But, then you'll get the error that:

> Property 'member' does not exist on type 'Entity'

Because it's a static member.

It's easy to see in the compiled js of the `Entity` class:

```
var Entity = (function () {
    function Entity() {
    }
    return Entity;
}());
Entity.member = [];
```

Clearly, `member` is not part of the prototype.

That's why you need to cast it, as my original answer says.

---

#### 2nd edit

Here's something that works and might be what you're after:

```
type EntityStatic = {
    new (...args: any[]): Entity;
    member: string[];
}

function Decorator(constructor: EntityStatic) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but  IMHO that solution is dirty. I always try to avoid using `as` to convert types. I've edited the question with something that would pass the correct typechecks but doesn't pass the `@Decorator` checkings.

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: So, I can't have in any form something extending Entity (extending its typeof, or something similar) so I can access to `T.member` without doing an explicity conversion.

Comment: No, I don't think so. Again, the problem is that you're using the `constructor.prototype` and static members are not part of the prototype

Comment: I've added a third try which doesn't work either. Now I don't use `constructor.prototype`, but I can't use T as a constructor.

Comment: Your 2nd edit its equivalent to the solution proposed at here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17454